# How do I package a Java program for Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have an application that currently a user downloads and runs an install script. I want to be able to take the JAR file and such that is generated by NetBeans and make it into a package that a user can download through a package manager. It needs to have menus implemented as well (the entries in the Debian menu that the user can click on).

Currently I am following through this tutorial: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

However, I am worried that I am going down some kind of rabbit hole in the wrong direction. Surely this must be something that is common?

What is the standard procedure for getting your JAR file to other people through packages?

Comment: Are you building using Ant, Maven, or the like? Would Netbeans be able to generate build scripts for use with Ant?

Comment: The usual mechanism is to distribute the JAR file (which is cross-platform). You seem to be building a deb file (which is a native package mechanism).

Comment: I am looking to build a package that will use the jar file. Basically, I want someone to be able to type apt-get install protocasedesigner and have it go ahead and install it on their system.

Comment: I assume Canonical won´t accept your program for the official repositories. So, having a deb file then means for users of your program that they have to register your server somewhere in the system to get your program (instead of just downloading it with a browser). Most won´t like that. And setting up a Apt-conformant server is an additional thing to learn for you. ... Just provide the normal jar file.

Comment: I'm thinking this belongs on http://askubuntu.com . It doesn't have anything to do with programming, but creating a package for a specific package manager.

Comment: @deviantfan you can also "run" a `.deb` that you download from the internet to install it.

Comment: @clcto: Yes, but why use a deb packet at all then ... A single jar file won´t have use for anything of the additional stuff Apt provides.

Comment: @deviantfan doesn't it give you the shortcuts that he is asking about

Comment: @deviantfan so that I can have it install/uninstall for the user instead of them having to delete files.

Comment: @clcto: Ok, 1:0 for you :)

Comment: @dah: Providing an "installer" just for the sake of installing? = More error-prone and bloated and security risk (because of root) and less control for the user because of ... nothing? :/ Well, if you think of that as a benefit ... The menu shortcut can be created without apt too

Comment: @deviantfan The software we provide is meant to be used by people that aren't very technical. If we can avoid having them to copy extra things or delete anything afterwords it is worth it. Also, there are a few other files/directories that need to be setup, I just wanted to provide a simple scenario.

Comment: @dah If they aren't very technical, then Linux is probably going to scare them more then a jar file.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not if it is already installed and all the have to do is follow our instructions on the web page. We frequently get users of linux that are new, also class path issues sometimes make jar files irritating. Also, linux is not scary if you are non technical, it's the semi-technical people that are scared of new things, not the oblivious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to:

- Install dpkg.
- Create a directory structure similar to how I would like it unpacked.
- Create a shell script that would copy it there.
- Run dpkg.